# Hosting site using apache in Debian

Tags: linux, apache, debian

I am logged in as root user and file permission for `sites-available/default` is 755.
I am unable to open the default file in Gedit as root user. When I try to do so, I get the following errors:

```
(gedit:8167): EggSMClient-WARNING **: Failed to connect to the session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
(gedit:8167): WARNING: Could not connect to session bus
```

Comment: I believe [server fault](http://serverfault.com/) is the right place to ask this.

Comment: are you sure you want to run gedit - supposedly gnome editor - as root? consider to use a console editor not requiring to invoke the whole graphical gorilla as root. Even though they don't sport pretty pictures to click on, some of them are rather comforable to use too.

Answer (score -1):

You should try [gksudo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gksudo) command to resolve this error

try `gksudo gedit`

Comment: sorry, could't help to -1 you for suggesting to run gnome stuff as root. That potentially endangers a system.